# Error in eval(ei, envir) : RuntimeError: You must compile your model before training/testing. Use `model.compile(optimizer, loss)`

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, runtime-error

I have the following code:

```
x <- seq(from = -10, to = 10, length.out = 1000)
y <- 0.1 * x * cos(x) + rnorm(1000, sd = 0.1)

my_model <- keras_model_sequential()
my_model <- my_model %>% layer_dense(units = 100, activation = "tanh" , input_shape =1)
my_model <- my_model %>% layer_dense(units = 100, activation = "tanh")
my_model <- my_model %>% layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "linear")

print(my_model)


my_training_fit <- keras::fit(my_model, x, y, epochs = 200 , batch_size = 100)
```

I'm getting the following Error Message:
Error in eval(ei, envir) :
RuntimeError: You must compile your model before training/testing. Use `model.compile(optimizer, loss)`.

What do I do here?

As you can see, I tried using `keras::fit` , but that led to a new issue.

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. In addition, [the documentation](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/quickstart/beginner) explicitly says “Before you start training, configure and compile the model using Keras `compile()`”